# Is there Java Desktop Wrapper for Linphone SIP client?

Tags: java, api, sip, linphone

I want to use Linphone API for my softphone, is there a java desktop wrapper available for this platform. Not android java.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only the Android Java wrapper. Use the C++ or C# wrapper for desktop.